# Number of hits report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

Can I create a custom report in google analytics to show me the total number of hits on a specific website? By "hit" I mean any item on the page that needs to load in order to view the page correctly. A better definition of what I mean can be found here:

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hit.html

Comment: If you want to check the no. of hits (as per the definition in the question), a webalyzer script on your apache logs would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't believe Google Analytics will tell you how many hits a page on your site is generating. Graphics, CSS, JS filese all count as hits to older Analytics programs. But that's a term and number which doesn't mean much. If you have 1000 images on a page what does it matter if you have 1000 hits? Your visitors are who matter not how many files your server is loading into your visitors browser.

On that note what you can do is run your website in Pingdom click the history tab, and see how many requests are made to the server (hits), optimizing websites these days for speed means reducing the requests to the server. CSS Sprites can turn multiple hits or requests to your server into one single request.

If you would like to know how many times a file is downloaded or some other action is taken on a file or element of a page you may want to look into Event tracking in Analytics.

I just optimized a site which had 389 requests to it's home page and got it down to 159 with room to improve.